# Photos received from SHAREit are not displayed in gallery

Tags: photos, shareit

Photos and videos received from SHAREit is not downloaded to gallery and I cannot view it in gallery.Why is this happening?

Comment: Check if those files are physically present on the device using file explorer. Delete files prefixed with dot in that folder  if present.

Comment: Community bump prevention: this question was closed because the question seems to have been abandoned (OP hasn't visited the site for more than 5 years, and no answers have been upvoted). If anyone can evaluate the existing answers, feel free to vote accordingly and reopen the question (or mod-flag the question requesting for reopening). For anyone else having the same issue, please post a new question and refer to this question as additional context.

Answer (score 0):

<sub>(Click image to enlarge)</sub>

[image: IMG: Shareit Folder]

Just Cut(or Copy) the Files from Shareit Folder and Paste it to your SDcard/Phone Memory.

Answer (score 0):

Shareit  latest version have some changes are occurred  , one of the change is it hides downloaded files, so we can't see downloaded files in internal , external storage or gallery etc.... , you can see downloaded files  using shareit app only, it is one of the way user can use permanently app